# Reloading plugin makes new item in menu

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I am writing a set of plugins doing complementary functionality. I want all the plugins under the same sub menu under Vector. This works fine, but when I am reloading the plugin during development, it will not remove the old menu item, it will just add on a new one, so that I end up with a lot of menu items for the same function, although only the last one is working.

[image: Screenshot]

So when I reload the plugin doing the "Load spectral data" part, I do not want to do anything on the menu for Altitude correction. (Which btw shows exactly the same when that is the one I am working on)

The relevant parts of my plugin:

```
metadata.txt:category=Vector

DataLoader.py (__init__) : self.menu = self.tr(u'&Spectral data')

DataLoader.py (initgui):
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Load spectral data'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

DataLoader.py (unload):
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginVectorMenu(
            self.tr(u'Load spectral data'),
            action)
```

What should I add to tell it to remove "Load spectral data" under the "Spectral data" submenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself...

I needed to specify the sub menu in the unload, so it becomes:

```
DataLoader.py (unload):
for action in self.actions:
    self.iface.removePluginVectorMenu(
        self.tr(u'&Spectral data'),
        action)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, different bug.  I used the Plugin Builder 3 to create a skeleton plugin.

In the `__init__` function, `self.menu` variable must contain the same param as the

```
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&My Plugin Name')
```

Above `self.menu` (i.e., My Plugin Name) must be equal to the `name` param in the `removePluginMenu` method below.  Documentation [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html#qgis.gui.QgisInterface.removePluginMenu)

```
    def unload(self):
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(self.tr(u'&My Plugin Name'), action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
```

A discrepancy between the two will result in a successful init, but a failure to unload from the menu.